# Relationship between curvature and "detour"

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, taylor-expansion

I am studying *Differential Geometry* and came across this exercise

> Let $c: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a regular curve. Let $L(h)$ be the length of the curve between points $c(t_0)$ and $c(t_0 + h)$.
>   Also define $d(h) := \lvert c(t_0 +h) - c(t_0) \rvert$.
>
> Show that $$
> \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{L(h) - d(h)}{(d(h))^3} = \frac{\kappa(t_0)^2}{24}
> $$
>   where $\kappa$ is the curvature of $c$.

I understand the geometric interpretation of the exercise and have shown that it is sufficient to show the statement for curves parameterized by arc length.

I also tried to use some kind of Taylor expansion of $c$ and $d$ but it did not work out.

Comment: Either when differential arc or differential segment tend to zero the curvature situation is same.

Comment: @Narasimham Could you explain how this is related to my problem?